# What happened after DNS TTL expired in intermediate Name Server?

Tags: dns, ttl

I have some questions to better understand DNS mechanism:

1) I know between clients and authoritative DNS server there are some intermediate DNS servers like ISP's one. What and where are the other types of them?

2) After the TTL of an NS record is expired in intermediate DNS servers, when do they refresh the addresses of names? Clients request? or right after expiration, they refresh records?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is off topic here as not related to programming.

But:

> I know between clients and authoritative DNS server there are some intermediate DNS servers like ISP's one. What and where are the other types of them?

There are only two types of DNS servers (we will put aside the stub case for now): it is either an **authoritative** nameserver (holding information about some domains and being the trust source of it) or a **recursive** one, attached to a cache, that is basically starting with no data and will then progressively, based on queries it gets, do various queries to get information.

Technically, a single server could do both, but it is a bad idea for at least the reason of the cache, and the different population of clients: an authoritative nameserver is normally open to any client as it needs to "broadcast" its data everywhere while a recursive nameserver is normally only for a selected list of clients (like the ISP clients).

There exists open public recursive nameservers today by big organizations: CloudFlare, Google, Quad9, etc. However, they have both the hardware, links, and manpower to handle all issues that come out of public recursive nameservers, like DDOS with amplification.

Technically you can have a farm of recursive nameservers, like big ISPs will need to do (or the above big public ones) because any single instance could not sustain all clients queries, and they can either share a single cache or work in a hierarchy, the bottom ones sending their data to another upstream recursive nameserver, etc.

> After the TTL of an NS record is expired in intermediate DNS servers, when do they refresh the addresses of names? Clients request? or right after expiration, they refresh records?

This historic naïve way could be summarized as: a request arrive, do I have it in my cache? If no, query outside for it and cache it. If yes, is it expired in my cache? If no, ship it to client, but if yes we need to remove it from cache and then do like it was not in cache from the beginning.

You then have various variations:

- some caches are not exactly honoring the TTLs: some are clamping values that are too low or too high, based on their own local policies. The most agreed reading on the specification is that the TTL is an indication of the maximum amount of time to keep the record in cache, which means the client is free to ditch it before. However, it should not rewrite it to a higher value if it thinks it is too low.
- caches can be kept along reboots/restarts, and can be prefetched, especially for "popular" records; in a way, the list of root NS is prefetched at boot and compared to the internal hardcoded list, in order to update it
- caches, especially in RAM, may need to be trimmed on, typically on an "oldest removed" case, in order to get places for new records coming along the way.
- so depending on how the cache is managed and which features it is requested to have, there may be a background task that monitor expirations and refresh records.

I recommend you to have a look at `unbound` as a recursive nameserver as it has various settings around TTL handling, so you could learn things, and then reading up the code itself (which brings us back on-topic kind of).

You can also read this document: https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-wkumari-dnsop-hammer-03.txt an IETF Internet-Draft about:

> The principle is that popular RRset in the cache are fetched, that is
>      to say resolved before their TTL expires and flushed.  By fetching
>      RRset before they are being queried by an end user, that is to say
>      prefetched, HAMMER is expected to improve the quality of experience
>      of the end users as well as to optimize the resources involved in
>      large DNSSEC resolving platforms.

Make sure to read Appendix A with a lot of useful examples, such as:

- > Unbound already does this (they use a percentage of TTL, instead of a number
  >   of seconds).
- > OpenDNS that they *also* implement something similar.
- > BIND as of 9.10, around Feb
  >   2014 now implements something like this
  >   (https://deepthought.isc.org/article/AA-01122/0/Early-refresh-of-cache-records-cache-prefetch-in-BIND-9.10.html), and enables it by
  >   default.
- > A number of recursive resolvers implement techniques similar to the
  >   techniques described in this document.  This section documents some
  >   of these and tradeoffs they make in picking their techniques.

And to take one example, the Bind one, you can read:

> BIND 9.10 prefetch works as follows. There are two numbers that control it. The first number is the "eligibility". Only records that arrive with TTL values bigger than the configured elegibility will be considered for prefetch. The second number is the "trigger". If a query arrives asking for data that is cached with fewer than "trigger" seconds left before it expires, then in addition to returning that data as the reply to the query, BIND will also ask the authoritative server for a fresh copy. The intention is that the fresh copy would arrive before the existing copy expires, which ensures a uniform response time.
>
> BIND 9.10 prefetch values are global options. You cannot ask for different prefetch behavior in different domains. Prefetch is enabled by default. To turn it off, specify a trigger value of 0. The following command specifies a trigger value of 2 seconds and an eligibility value of 9 seconds, which are the defaults.

Comment: Your explanation is complete. Thank you.

Comment: @M.Afrashteh Thanks, but I doubt it is complete, in fact I have just added a whole new block of data about prefetching with examples and further links to explore.